# hibernate list of objects

Tags: hibernate

when i try to get a list of objects i get following exception:

```
  Hibernate: select this_.newsId as newsId2_0_, this_.newsBrief as newsBrief2_0_, this_.newsContent as newsCont3_2_0_, this_.newsDate as newsDate2_0_, this_.newsTitle as newsTitle2_0_, this_.selected as selected2_0_ from NEWS this_
    Nov 15, 2013 11:04:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/strts-spring-hbnt-nomaven] threw exception [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "THIS_"."SELECTED": invalid identifier
```

ddl

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table NEWS
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."NEWS" 
   (    "NEWSID" NUMBER, 
    "NEWSTITLE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "NEWSBRIEF" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
    "NEWSCONTENT" VARCHAR2(2048 BYTE), 
    "NEWSDATE" DATE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;

--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index NEWS_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SYSTEM"."NEWS_PK" ON "SYSTEM"."NEWS" ("NEWSID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table NEWS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."NEWS" ADD CONSTRAINT "NEWS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("NEWSID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."NEWS" MODIFY ("NEWSDATE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."NEWS" MODIFY ("NEWSCONTENT" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."NEWS" MODIFY ("NEWSBRIEF" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."NEWS" MODIFY ("NEWSTITLE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "SYSTEM"."NEWS" MODIFY ("NEWSID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

news class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NEWS")
public class News {

    private boolean selected=false;
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "news_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "news_seq_gen", sequenceName = "news_seq")
    private int newsId;

    @Column(name="newsTitle", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String newsTitle;
    @Column(name="newsDate", nullable = false)
    private Date newsDate;
    @Column(name="newsBrief", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String newsBrief;
    @Column(name="newsContent", nullable = false, length = 2048)
    private String newsContent;
        //getters and setters 
}
```

the query :

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from News as News").list();
```

why does hibernate add number to the column names? and where is the problem? 
any suggestions would be appreciatated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Field Access Mode by placing `@Id` on a class property. This causes hibernate to think of all your fields as table columns. As I understand your DDL, `News.selected` is a transient property.

Try placing the `@Transient` annotation on `selected`.

Comment: yep, it helped :D thnx